# How to populate an array within another array

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I have an array that looks like this:

```
$scope.Pdfs = [
            [{
                column: 'Decription'
            }, {
                column: 'Name'
            }, {
                column: 'Age'
            }],
            [{
                column: 'Description'
            }, {
                column: 'Color'
            }, {
                column: 'Wheels'
            }],

        ];
```

While I was testing and implementing stuff in my controller I used it as it is, with hardcoded values. Now I want to populate this array from JSON, but I can't seem to succeed.

I tried with something like this, but it didn't work

```
$scope.Pdfs = [[],[]];    
$http.get('/Test/IndexVM').success(function (data) {
                $scope.Pdfs[0] = data;
            });
```

**EDIT:**

The JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "PdfConfigurationId": 0,
  "PdfConfigurationName": null,
  "PdfType": 0,
  "BrandName": null,
  "XMLColumns": [
    {
      "Name": "Description",
      "IsSelected": false,
      "ColumnPosition": 0,
      "ConcatFields": null
    },
    {
      "Name": "Colour",
      "IsSelected": false,
      "ColumnPosition": 0,
      "ConcatFields": null
    },
    {
      "Name": "KW/PS",
      "IsSelected": false,
      "ColumnPosition": 0,
      "ConcatFields": null
    },
    {
      "Name": "Chilometri x 1000 km",
      "IsSelected": false,
      "ColumnPosition": 0,
      "ConcatFields": null
    },
    {
      "Name": "Reg.",
      "IsSelected": false,
      "ColumnPosition": 0,
      "ConcatFields": null
    },
    {
      "Name": "Equipment",
      "IsSelected": false,
      "ColumnPosition": 0,
      "ConcatFields": null
    },
    {
      "Name": "No. PJVA",
      "IsSelected": false,
      "ColumnPosition": 0,
      "ConcatFields": null
    },
    {
      "Name": "Price",
      "IsSelected": false,
      "ColumnPosition": 0,
      "ConcatFields": null
    }
  ],
  "IsActive": false,
  "LastUpdatedDate": "/Date(-62135596800000)/",
  "LastUpdatedBy": null,
}
```

I want to populate with XMLColumns

Comment: And how the requested data look like?

Comment: What is the structure of the JSON?

Comment: You'll have to be much more precise than that. How didn't it work? What does `data` contain? Is the success callback even called? Use your browser dev tools to execute the code line by line and watch the values of variables.

Comment: What are expectations? You have a structure mismatch between the 2 and we have no idea what you do with this in view. people will help if you provide enough information to allow them to help

Comment: Basically I have a multiselect that has a dropdown where can be 2 options. The values of the first option are stored in the first array and the the values of the second in the last array. Now I want to populate the first array with the `Name` of the XMLColumns array.

Comment: Where is the display of the expected results?

Comment: Well I pass those values to another array and display them like this `<select multiple id="availabelist" size="10" style="width:275px" ng-change="OnAvailableChange()" ng-model="SelectedAvailItems" ng-options="i as i.column for i in AvailableListItems[selectPdfIndex] | orderBy:'column'"></select>`. I've managed to push objects to the array, but now I have another problem, the key has quotes, and I don't know how to create the object so that there won't be any quotes. Now the object looks like `{'column': 'Description'}` and I want it like this `{column: 'Description'}`